# Paired devices aren't shown on the list

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am a new android studio user. I am trying to build a BLE GATT service app. the app works fine for unpaired devices. However, the issue arises when I tried to scan for a device which is already paired. it does not show on the scan.

I am not using MainActivity, instead of that, I am using DeviceScanActivity as my Main. here's the snippet of that part:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 7500;

    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 255;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        verifyPermissionAndScan();

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){

            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

        } else {

            mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
            setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable && !mScanning) {

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer> mDevicesRssi = new HashMap<>();

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<>();//i removed BluetoothDevice from the diamond bracket
            mInflater = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {

            if (mDevicesRssi.containsKey(device)) {
                int oldRssi = mDevicesRssi.get(device);
                if (Math.abs(oldRssi - rssi) > 2) {
                    mDevicesRssi.put(device, rssi);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                mDevicesRssi.put(device, rssi);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            //
            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            //

            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                viewHolder.deviceRssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_rssi);
                viewHolder.deviceBonded = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_bonded);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            final String deviceName = device.getName();

            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);

            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
            updateBondedState(device, viewHolder);
            updateRssi(device, viewHolder);

            return view;
        }

        private void updateBondedState(BluetoothDevice device, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            switch(device.getBondState()) {
                case BOND_NONE:
                    viewHolder.deviceBonded.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case BOND_BONDING:
                    viewHolder.deviceBonded.setText(R.string.bonding_state);
                    viewHolder.deviceBonded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case BOND_BONDED:
                    viewHolder.deviceBonded.setText(R.string.bonded_state);
                    viewHolder.deviceBonded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void updateRssi(BluetoothDevice device, ViewHolder viewHolder) {

            final int rssi = mDevicesRssi.get(device);

            viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText(String.format("%s dBm", String.valueOf(rssi)));

        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device,rssi);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
        TextView deviceRssi;
        TextView deviceBonded;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private void verifyPermissionAndScan() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_already_given, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_REQUEST) return;

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_allowed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_not_allowed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DeviceControlActiviy class file:

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String TAG = DeviceControlActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";

    private TextView mConnectionState;
    private TextView mDataField;
    private String mDeviceName;
    private String mDeviceAddress;
    private ExpandableListView mGattServicesList;
    private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mGattCharacteristics =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();
    private boolean mConnected = false;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;

    private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
    private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);


        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(mDeviceAddress);
        mGattServicesList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.gatt_services_list);
        mGattServicesList.setOnChildClickListener(servicesListClickListner);
        mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
        mDataField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_value);

//        getActionBar().setTitle(mDeviceName);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        final Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                finish();
            }

//            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
            }
        }
    };

    private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
            new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                            int childPosition, long id) {

                    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                                mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();


                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {

                            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                        mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                            }

                            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }

                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    characteristic, true);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

    private void clearUI() {
        mGattServicesList.setAdapter((SimpleExpandableListAdapter) null);
        mDataField.setText(R.string.no_data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
        if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
            final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
        if (mConnected) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(true);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_connect:
                mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_disconnect:
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mConnectionState.setText(resourceId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            mDataField.setText(data);
        }
    }

    private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
        if (gattServices == null) return;
        String uuid = null;
        String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
        String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
                = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
            HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            currentServiceData.put(
                    LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
            currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                    gattService.getCharacteristics();
            ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                    new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
                HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                currentCharaData.put(
                        LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
                currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
                gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
            }
            mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
            gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
        }

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                gattServiceData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
                gattCharacteristicData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
        );
        mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
    }


    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }

}
```

I get the device name, address and RSSI for unpaired devices perfectly. but if the device is already paired it does not show on the device list, also if I click on a device on the unpaired device list, it does not automatically pair the device with the phone. I need to do it manually from the phone's BT setting.

Answer (score 0):

This displays all the devices the phone was paired with (even if it is not paired with currently)

**JAVA**

```
for(BluetoothDevice device : BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices()){

        device.getName(); // name  
        device.getAddress();// Address
    }
```

**KOTLIN**

```
for (device in BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().bondedDevices) {

            device.name // name
            device.address// Address

        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. can you please tell exactly where i should implement this function?

Comment: @AndroidPotato really depends on where you want to display it. you can add it in the snippet where you are initializing the adapter ``mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
            setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);`` pass the array to the adapter class when creating a new instance